# Is that a typo in polynomial splines equation in Tutz & Schmid (2016)?

Tags: survival, splines

I am reading Tutz & Schmid ["Modeling Discrete Time-to-Event Data"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) (2016) section 5.1 Smooth Baseline Hazard. Equation 5.3 offers a representation of polynomial splines of degree $d$:
$$
\gamma_0(t) = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}t + \dots + \gamma_{0d}t^d + \sum_{i=1}^{m_s} \gamma_{k+1}(t-\tau_i)^d_+
$$
where $(t-\tau_i)^d_+$ are truncated power functions. I gather the index $k+1$ in the sum should be $d+1$. Is that a typo, or did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: There is certainly some lack of context from the side of the authors if not outright typo. They brought $k$ out of nowhere; let me break down the terminologies: authors used $\gamma_{0(j-1)}$ for the coefficient related to $\phi_j(\cdot), ~j\in\{1,2,\cdots, d+1\}$ and for the truncated power functions $\phi_{d+1+i}(\cdot),~i\in\{1,\cdots,m_s\}, \gamma_{k+i}.$ I am not seeing any rationale behind the usage of $k.$ It could be $\gamma_{d+i}.$ However, this is my remark at a first glance if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: @User1865345, thank you. The book seems to lack a bit of polish, but since I am new to the topic, I often hesitate to make the call.